# count different cell-content in Excel 2019 with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

### **initial situation:**

I want to count the different content of a column (B) in conjunction with a condition in another column (A) (if ="X").
So far (without condition) I count the different contents as follows:

```
SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$BJ$11<>"")/COUNTIF($B$2:$BJ$11;$B$2:$B$11 &""))
```

[image]

## **question:**

**How can I include the condition from column A in the existing formula?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B13</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((A2:A11="X")/COUNTIFS(B2:B11,B2:B11,A2:A11,"X"),""))
```

---

Instead of <kbd>IFERROR( )</kbd>, using <kbd>IF( )</kbd> within <kbd>SUMPRODUCT( )</kbd>.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B13</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF($A$2:$A$11="X", 1/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, "X", $B$2:$B$11, $B$2:$B$11)), 0))
```

---

Caveat: While exiting the edit mode one needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> if not using `MS365`

---

Comment: Thank you for the solution that works as requested. I would like to include `TRIM`-function so that cells with spaces and empty cells are not counted. Should I ask a new question for this or can you give me a hint where I would have to add this?

Comment: @nerdyitguy can you try this once and let me know : `=SUMPRODUCT(IF(($A$2:$A$11="X")*(TRIM($B$2:$B$11)<>""), 1/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$11, "X", $B$2:$B$11, $B$2:$B$11)), 0))`

Comment: @nerdyitguy are you saying about the spaces in between the first and last name in customers column?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you your suggestion does exactly what I had hoped! You're right, there could be more than one space between the first and last name of a customer and thus differ. Is there also a possibility for this?

Comment: @nerdyitguy can you show a screenshot for this one

Comment: [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1wQX0Wu.png) all "Barry Kid" customers should be combined into one count.

Comment: @nerdyitguy you would need a helper column here: In adjacent column write and fill down `=TRIM(B2)` and then use the following formula `=SUMPRODUCT(IF((A2:A11="X")*(TRIM(B2:B11)<>""),1/COUNTIFS(C2:C11,C2:C11,A2:A11,A2:A11),0))`

Comment: @nerdyitguy but you wont need a helper if you have access to `MS365` `=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(TRIM(B2:B11),(TRIM(B2:B11)<>"")*(A2:A11="X"))))`

Comment: @nerdyitguy another way without helper : `=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(((A2:A11="X")*(TRIM(B2:B11)<>""))/COUNTIFS(A2:A11,"X",B2:B11,LEFT(TRIM(B2:B11),FIND(" ",TRIM(B2:B11))-1)&"*"),0))` try this one and let me know as well

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Everything works as desired. A real dream.

Comment: @nerdyitguy sounds good, glad to know all worked for you =)

Answer (score 0):

Here comes two options.

Use it as array formual (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter`, if you use early version (not Excel 365).

> =SUM(IF(A2:A11="X", 1/COUNTIFS(B2:B11, B2:B11, A2:A11, "X")))

---

Excel 365 has a new formula `UNIQUE` which makes it eaiser to get the unique list.

> =SUM(--ISTEXT(UNIQUE(IF(A2:A11="X",B2:B11,0))))

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggested solution. However, I prefer to use the one with `IFERROR`, because this way also empty cells are preventively taken into account.