# count all cell-content in Excel 2019 with condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Following up on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77010709/count-different-cell-content-in-excel-2019-with-condition/77010755?noredirect=1#comment135774937_77010755), I am looking for help to use Excel 2019

1. to count a number of cells that have content on one side (<>"") and after TRIM() should still contain content.

[image]

2. This formula is to be extended by a condition (Boolean value in column A => TRUE).

[image]

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(1*(A2:A11),1*(TRIM(B2:B11)<>"")) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The result can only be `TRUE` (`=1`) or `FALSE` (`=0`). The multiplication `1` is necessary so that the result `TRUE` or `FALSE` is also correctly recognized as `0` or `1` in the matrix.*

Formula used in cell <kbd>B13</kbd>.

1. `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(TRIM(B2:B11)<>""))`
2. `=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A2:A11),1*(TRIM(B2:B11)<>""))`

Try the formulas and report back if it works for you.